# Rating system for websites

Tags: releasing-data

I'm probably in the wrong StackExchange, but is there a rating system for websites?
For instance I wish there was some sort of curated site that said that "xyz" was a legitimate training site.

Maybe told me (roughly) how many customers they had, how long they've been in business, how many "employees" they have...
The kind of information that Hoovers would talk about in a business profile for a traditional business.

I suppose I could get their whois info, but that is pretty minimal.

Comment: there's no real oversight for domain registrations *unless* there's a dispute.  Back when I used to deal with SSL certificates, you used to have to prove who you were to the registrar (DUNS number, etc.) ... unfortunately, not all sites use HTTPS.  Even a registry of websites gets messy as you have companies that go under and get snatched up by some other person.  (either a doman squatter, porn site, or someone exploiting the good link karma of the other site)

Comment: Great question, there are several such databases. I have not yet heard about one which is open, but it might exist.

Comment: I like the idea of tying it to a DUNS number.  That would show some accountability...

Answer (score 2):

The Better Business Bureau has a listing of ["Safe, Secure and Approved Places to Visit Online"](http://www.bbb.org/online/consumer/default.aspx), but I have no idea how they license their data as their 'terms of use' link redirects to their front page.

(and the cynic in me thinks that companies paying to be included, which is BBB's economic model, is a conflict of interest (as their 'customer' are the businesses, to de-list a company is to lose a customer)

Answer (score 2):

Another source for website popularity and trustworthy-ness are sites like [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/) (which allows you to search without subscription) and comScore.

As with most companies where their greatest asset is their data, this is definitely *not open data* but may be what you're looking for.